# How to use google maps api v3 in nyromodal

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, nyromodal

Im trying to embed a map sing google maps api v3 in my nyromodal box but it doesnt happen.

I've tested the code without the modal and it works but when i try to open it on the nyromodal nothing appears.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive just figured out how to do it!

1 - Insert the js code for google in your index page with 'rel="forceload"' and 'rev="shown"' as the following:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false" rel="forceload" rev="shown"></script>`

2 - You insert the code that generates the map inside the modal page as the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready({
        var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapProp = {
            center: mylatlng,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("briefmap"), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mylatlng
        });
    });
</script>
```